# upload image from blackberry

Tags: blackberry

On my code I got a image from camera but I want to upload it on the server, I convert the image to byte array I sent it to the url of php server can any one tell me Which type of code I have to write.

One problem is that the byte array data is 11 character in length my PM told me that the byte you got is too small

I got the byte array as follows 
[B@f359616f

when i run this code at php side the imagecreatefromstring($images); not create the image

Any code plz help me

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're calling 'toString()' on a byte array.  This means you are calling the default implementation of toString provided by the VM, which is to format the type name, then '@' then some object specific int, likely the object identity hash code.

Typically, StackOverflow questions include source code.  In this case, you would want to include the function that is uploading the image data.  People helping you would be interested in the datatypes involved, and how you are formatting and delivering that data to the server's php script.